# DB2 BOOLEAN type, EXISTS predicate and nullability strange behavior

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm using DB2 LUW v11.1.4.5,

It seems that EXISTS predicate, when FALSE returns NULL (is it documented ?)
In the following query on `X is null` is `true`, all the rest acts like `FALSE` is a synonym for `NULL`, but the metadata say all the columns are not nullable
(see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=be1a38a27a8660d60eafb40c58e39fc4))

```
with boolstmt as
(
  select  'exists' stmt,
    exists(select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 where ibmreqd = 'N') as x
  from sysibm.sysdummy1
 )
select
 stmt,
 x,
 x is null "x is null",
 not x "NOT x",
 x = FALSE "x = FALSE",
 smallint(x) "smallint(x)",
 char(x) "char(x)"
from boolstmt
```

now with the following query every column is nullable, it shows that `x` really is `NULL` with `EXISTS`

```
with boolstmt as
(
  select  'exists' stmt,
    exists(select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 where ibmreqd = 'N') as x
  from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select  'count' stmt,
    (select count(*) from sysibm.sysdummy1 where ibmreqd = 'N') > 0 as x
  from sysibm.sysdummy1
 )
select
 stmt,
 x,
 x is null "x is null",
 not x "NOT x",
 x = FALSE "x = FALSE",
 smallint(x) "smallint(x)",
 char(x) "char(x)"
from boolstmt
```

My question is : did someone know about it, it seems to me that's a problem on the server but do you know if it may come from the JDBC driver (using 4.27.25) ? Is the problem still there using later versions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting question with the answer that is not so interesting: in this trivial example your `EXISTS` is optimized away, so an attempt to reference this predicate evaluation result is undefined. If you run `db2exfmt` (or another tool that can retrieve the "optimized" version of the statement), you will see that this is what gets executed in the end:

```
SELECT 'exists' AS "STMT",
   $INTERNAL_FUNC$() AS "X",
   $INTERNAL_FUNC$() AS "x is null",
   $INTERNAL_FUNC$() AS "NOT x",
   $INTERNAL_FUNC$() AS "x = FALSE",
   SMALLINT($INTERNAL_FUNC$()) AS "smallint(x)",
   CHAR($INTERNAL_FUNC$()) AS "char(x)",
   $INTERNAL_FUNC$() AS "Y",
   $INTERNAL_FUNC$() AS "y is null",
   $INTERNAL_FUNC$() AS "NOT y",
   $INTERNAL_FUNC$() AS "y = FALSE",
   SMALLINT($INTERNAL_FUNC$()) AS "smallint(y)",
   CHAR($INTERNAL_FUNC$()) AS "char(y)" 
FROM (SELECT NULL 
FROM (VALUES ) AS Q1 
WHERE ('Y' = 'N')) AS Q2
```

This is likely Working As Designed™, because predicates, of which `EXISTS` is one, are not *meant* to be used in place of expressions. Db2 tries to do its best to *turn* predicate evaluation outcomes into values, but the optimizer has an upper hand.

Things work as you expect when you use expressions and predicates where they respectively belong:

```
with boolstmt as
(
  select  'exists' stmt,
    case when exists(select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 where ibmreqd = 'N') then true else false end as x
  from sysibm.sysdummy1
 )
```

Comment: OK  thanks, you explained it. I guess that's why `values exists(select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 where ibmreqd = 'N')` says SQLCODE=-582. But if the result column had just been mark nullable I had not spent half a day wondering why sometimes `FALSE or TRUE = FALSE`